# Control UIBarButtonItem resizing iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigationBar set up with an image for titleView as well as a leftBarButtonItem and a rightBarButtonItem.

The problem is that when I change the title of the leftBarButtonItem to a wider one it causes the titleView to jump a couple of pixels to the right.

So how can I control the resizing behaviour of barButtonItems?

My code where I create the buttons and image:

```
UIImage *navBarTitleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header_icon.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:navBarTitleImage];

UIBarButtonItem *unitButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Metric", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(changeUnits)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = unitButton;

UIBarButtonItem *resetButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Reset", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(resetValues)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = resetButton;
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: But honestly, did you even _try_ looking at the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes I did. And I've been searching for a solution here and elsewhere for two days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the button is going to have more than one title over the course of time, set either its `width` or its `possibleTitles`.